# How to override os.environ.get() for django settings.py file

Tags: python-3.x

I am using some environment variables. I can get them with `os.environ.get("somekey", None)`.I want to apply some logic if a line from environment variable has a flag that I put before.

example line in env:

```
FILE_PASS=password
FILE_NAME=examplefile #CHECK
```

in settings.py:

```
file_pass = os.environ.get("FILE_PASS", "")
file_name = os.environ.get("FILE_NAME","default_file")
```

I do not want to write `my_custom_env()` because I want everyone keep using os.environ.get function behind my logic.

How can I do that?
Edit: Is this calling monkey patching?
EDIT2: I think what I want is something like this

```
import os
def new_os_environ(key, default=''):
    env = os.environ
    line = env.get(key, default)
    if "#CHECK" in line:
        #do some stuff
    return line

os.environ.get = new_os
os.environ.get("FILE_NAME","heey")
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question I'm afraid. "I want to apply some logic if a line from environment variable has a flag that I put before." - what does this mean, can you bve more specific and give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Could you check edited question?

Comment: You won't find `#CHECK` in the line, because it will be treated as a comment in the `env` file. So this approach won't  work.

Comment: What if using something like `!CHECK` ? I just want to mark lines with whatever it is.

Comment: I think you're into the realms of "hacky" code there - see my suggestion in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
    if "#CHECK" in line:
        #do some stuff
```

will not work because the `#CHECK` will be treated as a comment, and will not show up with the `env.get` command.

You could read the file line by line I suppose, but a better way would simply be to add a new variable into the env file. Something along the lines of:

```
CHECK=TRUE
```

Then you can specifically check whether this value exists and code accordingly.

```
check = os.environ.get("CHECK","FALSE")
if check == "TRUE":
   # Do your stuff herre
```

If you want boolean values straight off, use 1 and zero. I prefer text strings TRUE and FALSE because I think they stand out more and make it more obvious what you are doing, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: I jsut want to mark a line with lets say `!CHECK` and for example encode only marked line. In my example getting `FILE_NAME` with `os.environ.get("FILE_NAME") ` and if it is marked with `!CHECK` let's say encode it to base64

Comment: I mean I wanted to ask about adding a behavior to os.environ.get() function.

Comment: You could retrieve the line, then parse it for whatever indicator you put in, but I would advise against this approach.